# IOS UIWebView Orientation issue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, uiwebview

I am new to iOS just have to make a small native app that loads a URL with is hosted on IIS and made on Jquery mobile.
The issue is having when i change the orientation it is clipping from right side while the same thing is working correctly on all android devices.
Please help me out

this is my code

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIWebView *webView=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0,768,1024)];


    NSString *httpSource=@"http://www.mydomain.com";
    NSURL *fullUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:httpSource];
    NSURLRequest *httpRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fullUrl];
    webView.delegate=self;
    [webView loadRequest:httpRequest];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set Autoresizing mask for your webView, or you can use Autolayout.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

       [super viewDidLoad];

       //Here you use the frame of Total View, irrespective of device type
       UIWebView *webView=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

       //Autoresizemask
       webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
       NSString *httpSource=@"http://www.mydomain.com";
       NSURL *fullUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:httpSource];
       NSURLRequest *httpRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fullUrl];
       webView.delegate=self;
       [webView loadRequest:httpRequest];
       [self.view addSubview:webView];
     }
```

Comment: Thanks chandu your code works.
but what about if i want this app to be run on iphone and ipad. What should be width and height for that

Comment: You can use the total frame of the View as your webView's frame,so that you don't have to set frames manually, irrespective of which device. I suggest you to read thoroughly apple documentation. Check my updated code.

Comment: Here is the Apple documentaion link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `UIWebView` frame when device is rotate. Try bellow code

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

    [webView setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)]; 
}
```